# C# / Azure - How to enable keep-alive connection for Telegram bot

Tags: c#, azure, telegram-bot

I would like to create my own Telegram Bot so I hosted it on MS Azure. I have only free student starter subscription so I've chosen the "Web App Service" option there. I've created a new Web API project, have written some code to test it and published it. Everything was working OK but there was only one problem. After a few hours(maybe even less, I didn't measure it) of being idle the bot stopped responding and the only way to make him alive again was to refresh the

> http://appname.azurewebsites.net/api/values

page. How to keep him alive all the time?

Comment: listen to disconnect event and reconnect, no idea what your client is though so can't answer

Comment: @LukeHutton I'm using the Telegram.Bot package and the TelegramBotClient doesn't seem to have evnet listener like that but I'm not sure.

Comment: looks like there is an ```OnReceiveError``` event handler, could ```if (!Bot.IsReceiving) { Bot.StartReceiving(); }``` in it

Answer (score 2):

I'm no familiar with what plans are available in student subscriptions. This sounds like the web app goes to "sleep" if there's no activity.

You can get around this by enabling the **Always On** feature in the web apps settings. Enabling Always on will keep your app from being recycled by pinging it regularly and this way keeping it alive.

Always on, as a feature, is available for all Basic, Standard and Premium plans.

See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure) for more information. Also, here's a comparison between the different plans.

Comment: Now I'm using a HTTP monitor on uptimerobot.com to refresh the web service every 10 minutes but after (for example) one hour of being idle, when I want the bot to send messages for me it sends and duplicates them a few times (as if a few instances were running but I don't know how to check it). Where should I look for the solution for that?